# How to get required output as described below in Java?

Tags: java

I'm tryng to write a simple program called ShopAssit in Java  where the menu should read:

```
Welcome to ShopAssit

1. Show Shop
2. Show Price
3. Minimum Price from different shops
4. minimum price from one particular shop
5. Discount available 
0. Exit

Enter an option:
```

The following are required outputs:

```
1. when user enters 1:
output should read;
Welcome to ShopAssit
1.Show Shop
2.Show Price
3.Minimum Price from different shops
4.minimum price from one particular shop
5.Discount available 
0.Exit
Enter an option:1
Show Shop
Enter an Option:

When user enters 2, output should read:
Welcome to ShopAssit
1.Show Shop
2.Show Price
3.Minimum Price from different shops
4.minimum price from one particular shop
5.Discount available 
0.Exit
Enter an option:1
Show shop
Enter an option:2
Show price
Enter an Option:

when 3 is entered, it should read;
Welcome to ShopAssit
1.Show Shop
2.Show Price
3.Minimum Price from different shops
4.minimum price from one particular shop
5.Discount available 
0.Exit
Enter an option:1
show shop
Enter an option:2
Show Price
Enter an Option:3
Minimum Price from different shops
Enter an option:

when 4 is entered, it should read:
Welcome to ShopAssit
1.Show Shop
2.Show Price
3.Minimum Price from different shops
4.minimum price from one particular shop
5.Discount available 
0.Exit
Enter an option:1
show shop
Enter an option:2
Show Price
Enter an option:3
Minimum Price from different shops
Enter an option
minimum Price from one particular shop
Enter an Option:

and when user enters 5, the following output is expected;
Welcome to ShopAssit
1.Show Shop
2.Show Price
3.Minimum Price from different shops
4.minimum price from one particular shop
5.Discount available 
0.Exit
Enter an option:
Discount available
Enter an Option:

when 0 is entered the following output is expected:
Welcome to ShopAssit
1.Show Shop
2.Show Price
3.Minimum Price from different shops
4.minimum price from one particular shop
5.Discount available 
0.Exit
Enter an option
Discount available
Enter an option:
Exit
```

and finally a error message if one of the above is not met.

I have started the program as shown below but it's not giving me the required output mentioned above.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyShopAssistant {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     System.out.println("Welcome to Shop Assistant Application.");
     System.out.println("1.Show Shop.");
     System.out.println("2.Show Price.");
     System.out.println("3.Minimum price from different shops.");
     System.out.println("4.Minimum price from one particular shop.");
     System.out.println("5.Discount Available.");
     System.out.println("0.Exit.");
     System.out.println();

    Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter an Option:");
    int menuNumber = input.nextInt();

switch (menuNumber)

     {   
     case 1:
          System.out.println("Show Shop!");
          System.out.print("Enter an option:");
          System.out.print(input.nextInt());

     case 2:
          System.out.println("Show Price.");
          System.out.print("Enter an option:");
          System.out.print(input.nextInt());
     case 3:
          System.out.println("Minimum Price from different shops");
          System.out.print("Enter an Option:");
          System.out.print(input.nextInt());
     case 4:
          System.out.println("4.Minimum price from one particular shop.");
          System.out.print("Enter an Option:");
          System.out.print(input.nextInt());      
     case 5:
          System.out.println("Discount!");
          System.out.print("Enter an Option:");
          System.out.print(input.nextInt());
     case 0:
         System.out.print("Exit!");
         System.out.print(input.nextInt());
     default: 
          System.out.println("Enter value between 0 and 5.");
          System.out.print("Enter an Option:");
          System.out.print(input.next());
          break;       
       }
     }       
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using a `break;` between the different cases?

Comment: ...And what output is it giving?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger figure out what your program is doing?  Learning to debug your own code is an important part of your homework.  Either way, if you want help you need to explain (clearly) what incorrect behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: Please make an effort to format your posts using the tools provided. If your homework problem looks like a dump-and-run then you'll be notified by way of downvotes. Don't do this too often - a new account with a few -6 questions will be prevented from asking new questions.

Answer (score 3):

you need to add break; after every case, so it should look like this

```
case(number): 
//do stuff
break;
//other cases
```

Comment: as per the required output I guess I should include a break after option 4.

Comment: @Dennis Joel you do know that case 2 wont include output thats written in cases above it? either create a method that includes the parts you repeat and call it, or mechanically repeat everything in every case. if you have cases that show the same output, you could do case(1||2): which means case 1 or 2

Comment: @mursiuke, thanks for the tip, Ill try work on that.

Comment: @Dennis Joel if i solved your problem, please accept it as answer, and if not, try to explain exactly whats still wrong with the output

Comment: The output looks fine but It cannot discretely take readings from numbers 1 to 5. to give the output. in other words if I enter any random number(integer), the program will still run. I am not really sure how I will do that without including break after each case..

Comment: @Dennis Joel use a if clause- if(input>5||input<1){break;} - you can also add a error message in the {}; p.s. keep in mind that stackoverflow should be used as a last resort- aka, try googling it first.

Answer (score 1):

> when 0 is entered the following output is expected: Welcome to Shop

As you have it right now, when 0 is entered you'll get Exit. But like everyone else said, gotta add those break statements.

There's a good simple example here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: @Dave, thanks I might as well include break in each case.